# How to display layout for static block pages for magento1.9.1?

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0, static-block

[image]i created static block pages like about us, contact us and banner. But the **storeview** can not display, So please help me how to add layout for all static block pages...how to display storeview tab in static block page creation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to assign them in xml file i.e. Layout file,

like,

```
 <block type="catalog/category_view" name="category.products" template="catalog/category/view.phtml">
```

Now in CategoryController of catalog module under ViewAction method when $this->loadLayout() is called, this template file will be opened.

Comment: May i know why (storeview) doesnot displays???

Comment: Check with your packages, are they are correctly assigned or not. Also check wheather you have enabled your storeview.

Comment: how and where i will enable storeview ??and  how to check packages?

Comment: To enable a storeview go to System > Manage > Add store view (right most tab)

Comment: And to check packages go to System > Configuration > Design and check your packages

Comment: default storeview is enabled and rwd packages is present but still storeview is not displayed while adding static block pages

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/51059/discussion-between-mrunmay-deswandikar-and-abdul).